# Spring MVC page not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a newbie to Spring framework especially Spring MVC.

I am writing a code which takes in a Name in a form and displays it on the page. So index.jsp is the form class in which on hitting the sayHello button the request should get forwarded to another page hello.jsp and prints the message. But on clicking the button it is giving 404 error. According to me all the names and configurations are fine but it just doesn't go and prints the message.

index.jsp

```
<h2>Form</h2>
<form action="./hello.html">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="sayHello"/>
</form>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloController.java

```
 package com.spring.mvc.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello.html")
    public String testMVC(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Anshul !!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

helloworld-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.mvc.controllers" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

hello.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved.
I think the issue was with my system or eclipse itself.
Ran the code on other machine and it worked just fine.
Thanks for replying @alex.b

Answer (score -1):

Check with your directory
make sure that you have build path for required jar files 
if it is correct it should work

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Right, that is indeed very annoying. I would suggest you [answer questions you can answer and wait till you gain the reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).